# Do document-oriented databases exist which do not fall in a subclass of NoSQL databases but are relational?

Tags: database, relational-database, document-oriented-db, nosql

I'm doing research on a project about document-oriented databases(dod). My question is if their are any dod which are not NoSQL? If I google this then I only get results which describe NoSQL or Relational databases or the differences between them. If somebody with knowlegde about dod would point me in the right direction. That will be much appreciated.

Comment: A NoSQL database is basically a database that is not relational. So document-oriented databases are a subset of NoSQL dbs. You can find different subsets and examples on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Types_and_examples_of_NoSQL_databases)

Answer (score 0):

Graph database is a class of NoSQL database that is relational with strong ACID guarantees.